# Lost my nib connection: how to get it back?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nib, xib

I am writing my very first genuine program for the IPhone.  In the course of developing it, I decided to rename a subsidiary view controller (not RootViewController), so I renamed the .h and .m and .xib files.

I had to modify a small amount of code, such as import statements, but the coding effort quickly recovered and all compiled and ran.

However, my view for the view controller doesn't appear when pushed on the stack:  I just get a blank view.  Apparently renaming the nib file to agree with the view controller is not enough.  How to fix?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

John R. Doner

Comment: Not answering your question, but a small tip for the next time you want to rename a class: right-click on the class name in the header file and choose "Refactor", then rename it. Then Xcode will change everything needed for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the class of the File's Owner object in the nib file?